# How to get updated data which is posted as soon as the POST request is called? AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a scenario wherein according to the course_id, I add modules into it.
Now whenever I add a new module, I have to refresh the page to get the newly added module along with the old ones. How do I fetch the data posted(new ones) as soon as the request is called.

```
const fetchModule = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8083/getmodules/${course_id}`)
          .then(res => {
            updateModule(res.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          });
      }, [course_id]);
}
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
            const course = { course_id, course_name };
            const formdata = { module_id, module_type, module_name, duration, course };
            axios.post("http://localhost:8083/createmodule", formdata)
            .then( res => 
            {
                console.log(res.data);
                fetchModule();  
            })
          
  }
```

Now the fetchModule function fetches the module, so as soon as we post the data in then I call the fetchModule, but this doesnt seem to work. Please help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking when data is posted from anywhere (I or another user adds a module), or just if the current user adds it? I.E., do you want to update anytime the data changes on the server, or just when you, the current user, submit the new module.

Comment: When the current user adds the new module

Comment: Is this the code you are using? You can't call `useEffect` (or any other hook) from a function that isn't a component (see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).